# VoiceOver to focus the whole receive text area only

Tags: iphone, ios, voiceover

in my iPhone application I am usinf VoiceOver functionality. I have a UITextView with some text. It is now possible to focus each line in  text area. How can I implement possibility to focus the whole receive text area only.

Comment: Why do you want to change the native behaviour of a native component? Are you sure that your users won't expect the native text view behaviour?